# Folder structure unmasks [erroneous?] CS0246: "The type or namespace name 'IAsyncRepository<>' could not be found"

Tags: c#, namespaces, directory-structure

RE: DotNet 6.0 and VS Community 2022 (64-bit) - CurrentVersion 17.1.1

This code results in a compiler error CS0246:

```
using GloboTicket.TicketManagement.Domain.Entities;

namespace GloboTicket.TicketManagement.Application.Contracts.Persistence
{
    public interface IOrderRepository: IAsyncRepository<Order>
    {
    }
}
```

This following code does not (note the use of the prefix "Persistence." to refer to IAsyncRepository):

```
using GloboTicket.TicketManagement.Domain.Entities;

namespace GloboTicket.TicketManagement.Application.Contracts.Persistence
{
    public interface IOrderRepository: Persistence.IAsyncRepository<Order>
    {
    }
}
```

Why is this needed? IAsyncRepository and IOrderRepository are siblings in the same folder - i.e., in the same namespace!

The reference can be used without the "Persistance." prefix if the "where T : class" is deleted in the base type "IAsyncRepository":

```
namespace GloboTicket.TicketManagement.Application.Contracts.Persistence
{
    public interface IAsyncRepository<T> where T : class
    {
      /...
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts... 1) It's possible the namespace is different even though they are in the same folder, e.g. if you create a file and then move it, it will still be in the same namespace unless you change it after you move it. 2) It's possible there are two `IAsyncRepository` interfaces defined and the reference is ambiguous without the additional `Persistence` value.

Comment: There is only one "IAsyncRepository" in the entire solution directory, and the namespace "...\Persistence" is the same for all involved classes.

Comment: And now I can't duplicate this problem... Argh!